# how to sum value row to row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say i have data in mysql like this :

```
date | value
2010 | 1
2011 | 4
2012 | 2
2013 | 3
```

i want the result like this :

```
date | value
2010 | 1
2011 | 5
2012 | 7
2013 | 10
```

I thought this would be simple. I'm trying this:

```
select tabelA.date, sum(value)
from tabelA
inner join (select date from tabelA group by date) b on tabelA.date > b.date
group by tabelA.date
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. It seems like a simple thing to want to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.35-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    b.date,( SELECT sum( a.`value` ) FROM aa a WHERE a.date <= b.date ) value
FROM
    aa b 
GROUP BY
    b.date
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in MySQL 8+ is window functions:

```
select a.date,
       sum(a.value) over (order by a.date)
from tabelA a
order by a.date;
```

In older versions, variables are probably the best approach, but they have to be used carefully:

```
select date, (@csum := @csum + value) as running_sum
from (select a.date, a.value as value
      from tableA a
      order by a.date
     ) a cross join
     (select @csum := 0) params;
```

In particular, you want the `order by` in the subquery to be sure that the data is processed in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable:

```
SET @cumulative := 0;
SELECT date, (@cumulative := @cumulative+value) as value FROM tabelA
```

This will just keep track of current sum. It's basically a minor adaptation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895127/487813) to get a row number.